# What's the source of the sample at the beginning of Moss Icon's "Hate in me"?

Tags: rock, sample

I can find [the lyrics](https://genius.com/Moss-icon-hate-in-me-lyrics) sung in the song at Genius.com but what's the source of the sample at the beginning of "[Hate in me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CP2_pBsg1Y)"? I can't even understand all of it.